# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. [Django-React Setup]

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, cors

Trying to call a Django API via React. But CORS does not seem to be working properly.

settings.py (django)

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'rest_framework',
    'accounts',
    'products',
    'corsheaders',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

API in chrome browser,

```
GET /products/view/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "product_updated",
        "image": "...",
        "cost": "50.00",
        "avail_quantity": 100,
        "desc": "Good",
        "rating": "3.60",
        "users_rated": 100
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Dark Coffee",
        "image": "...",
        "cost": "50.00",
        "avail_quantity": 100,
        "desc": "Good",
        "rating": "3.60",
        "users_rated": 100
    }
]
```

React component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Dashboard extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: '127.0.0.1:8000',
      productList: []
    }
     this.fetchProducts = this.fetchProducts.bind(this)
  }

 fetchProducts(){
     fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/view`, {
         method: "GET",
          }).then(res=> res.json())
            .then(res=> {
              console.log(res, typeof res, res.length)
            this.setState({productList: res})
          })
      console.log(this.state.productList)
}


 componentWillMount(){
    this.fetchProducts()
 }

render() {
  var list = []
  for (let i = this.state.productList.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        list.push(<li>{this.state.productList[i].name}</li>)
        console.log(list)
      }
  return (
    <div className="dashboard">

    <h1>Welcome To Bear State Coffee!</h1>
    <h3>Products: </h3>
    <ul>
      {list}
    </ul>

    </div>
  )
}
}

export default Dashboard
```

Console on running Dashboard on react server

> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/view: Redirect from
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/view' to
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/view/' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not
>   allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
>   request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>   localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Edit: Set of response from browser (http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/view/)

```
OPTIONS /products/view/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "name": "Products",
    "description": "GET: For viewing all products",
    "renders": [
        "application/json",
        "text/html"
    ],
    "parses": [
        "application/json",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "multipart/form-data"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post a set of request/response headers for a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/view` from the browser? The solution provided by @rahamin will 'work', in that it will stop CORS errors in development. However, as soon as you move this to Production, it will fail for users who don't have that extension.

Comment: @roryhewitt Added. Yes, precisely the same reason I'm asking for a fix in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround:

- Use the chrome extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)
- Use proxy: instead of accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/view`, use a proxy like `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` as a prefix: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/view`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
By just adding the extension, the issue is fixed. Although, I still wonder what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Trying to access a different domain without permission is forbidden due to security reasons. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS