# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource React Django issue

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, create-react-app

I used django-cors-headers for managing CORS in my Django app.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'core',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ("x-requested-with", "content-type", "accept", "origin", "authorization", "x-csrftoken")
```

And my React look likes the following:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Make an API call to the backend
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/core')
        .then((response) => {
            const namesArray = response.data.map(item => item.title);
            setNames(namesArray);
            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
```

I also include the following in `package.json` in my react app.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000/core",
```

It's still throwing error
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/core' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Please help, thank you!!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058042/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-d?rq=2